# Spring-Security migration from 2.0.4 to 4.2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, icefaces-1.8

I have an application running with spring-security version 2.0.4 and now i need to change that to version 4.2.0...

I create login page with this sample:

http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/spring-security-basic.html

**springSecurityLogin.jspx**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">
    <ice:outputDeclaration doctypeRoot="HTML"
                           doctypePublic="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                           doctypeSystem="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"/>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ice:form partialSubmit="false">
        <ice:panelGrid columns="2">
            <ice:outputLabel value="User Name" for="j_username"/>
            <ice:inputText id="j_username"
                           value="#{loginBean.userId}" size="40"
                           maxlength="80"/>
            <ice:outputLabel value="Password" for="j_password"/>
            <ice:inputSecret id="j_password"
                             value="#{loginBean.password}" size="40"
                             maxlength="80"/>
        </ice:panelGrid>
        <ice:commandButton actionListener="#{loginBean.login}" value="Login"/>
        <ice:messages style="color: red;"/>
    </ice:form>
    </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

my **login** method:

```
public void login(ActionEvent e) throws java.io.IOException {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/spring-authentication/j_spring_security_check?j_username=" + userId + "&j_password=" + password);
}
```

That was working... But when i change the spring security version to **4.2.0** I got http error 404 when try to login.

Someone knows whats is happening?

Comment: There are migration guides out there.

Comment: The migration guide don't work with icefaces...

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following...

spring-security allow authentication http call with GET or POST, after migrate, by default it's allow only POST calls.

To solve it, just insert the following line on your `AuthenticationFilter`:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setPostOnly(false);
```

This solve the problem.